# How to find the best way to distribute N observations into M groups?

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, optimization

I will try to explain my problem in the clearest way possible. Assume we have the `df` dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

users = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h', 'a','b','c','g','h', 'b','c','d','e']
groups = ['g1']*8 + ['g2']*5 + ['g3']*4
scores = [0.54, 0.02, 0.78, 0.9 , 0.98, 0.27, 0.25, 0.98, 0.47, 0.02, 0.8, 0.51, 0.28, 0.53, 0.01, 0.51, 0.6 ]
df = pd.DataFrame({'user': users,
                   'group': groups,
                   'score': scores}).sort_values('score', ascending=False)
```

This will return something like this:

```
   user group  score
7     h    g1   0.98
4     e    g1   0.98
3     d    g1   0.90
10    c    g2   0.80
2     c    g1   0.78
16    e    g3   0.60
0     a    g1   0.54
13    b    g3   0.53
11    g    g2   0.51
15    d    g3   0.51
8     a    g2   0.47
12    h    g2   0.28
5     f    g1   0.27
6     g    g1   0.25
1     b    g1   0.02
9     b    g2   0.02
14    c    g3   0.01
```

Each user has a certain score when belonging to each group. The thing is that each group can have a limited number of members. These numbers are stored in a dictionary:

```
members = {'g1': 3,
           'g2': 2,
           'g3': 1}
```

And here is the problem: I have to choose the best way to distribute the users in groups, taking into account their scores and the number of users each group can host.

If we take a look at the dataframe above, the best way to assign the users to the groups would be the following one:

1. The highest scores are the ones assigned to `h`, `e` and `d` belonging to `g1`. Given that `g1` can take up to 3 members, then these three users are assigned to it. Now `g1` can't take any more members.
2. The following best score is the one assigned to `c` belonging to `g2`. Therefore `g2` now has one slot left.
3. Observe that the following score also refers to `c`, but this user was already assigned, so it can't be assigned twice. Thus, it must be ignored. The same happens with the following one, which relates `e` (user that was already assigned to `g1)` to `g3`.
4. The following one relates `a` to `g1`, but this group is full. Thus, it has to be ignored as well.
5. The process has to go on until all groups are full, or until there are no more rows left to fill the groups (in this case, some groups will have free slots left).

The solution I found is this one:

```
final = pd.DataFrame([])
# As long as there are non-assigned users and groups with free slots...
while len(df):
    # Take the first row (i.e. the best score of the rows left)
    i = df.first_valid_index()
    # If there are free slots...
    if members[df.loc[i,'group']] > 0:
        # Subtract 1 from the slots left of this group
        members[df.loc[i,'group']] -= 1
        # Append this row to the 'final' DataFrame
        final = final.append(df.loc[i])
        # Delete all rows belonging to this user, as it was already assigned
        df = df.loc[df.user != df.loc[i,'user']]
    # If the group has no free slots left...
    else:
        # Delete all rows belonging to this group, as it is already full
        df = df.loc[df.group != df.loc[i,'group']]
final = final.groupby('group').agg({'user': ['unique','count']})
```

This returns the following DataFrame:

```
            user      
          unique count
group                 
g1     [h, d, f]     3
g2        [c, g]     2
g3           [b]     1
```

Here is the problem: **this code takes forever to run in real life.** I have more than 20 million different users, and there are approximately 10 different groups to fill. So this approach is really non-viable.

Is there a more efficient way to do this? **I'm willing to take a sub-optimal solution if necessary. Namely, assigning the almost-best users to every group...** If that makes sense.

Comment: What does probability for a user to appear in a group really mean in your case? Is it a sort of preference, in decreasing order? Because you are going to return a single selection regardless of the "probabilities"...

Comment: @MadPhysicist Well, they are some kind of scores. Maybe the word "probability" isn't the best term. I'll change that in the question. The selection should be done as described in the question, though, regardless of the actual meaning of the `score` column.

Comment: Makes sense. Just to clarify, your question is then how to optimize your existing  algorithm?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yes. The loop I've written at the end of the OP works alright when working with small groups. That *is* the optimal solution for my problem. The thing is that this doesn't work when there are millions of rows. Therefore, I'm looking for another solution, even if the output is not the actual optimum but something close to it.

Comment: Why don't you replace you data with a `groupby(['user'],as_index=False).agg({'score':'max'})` in order to avoid this duplication of users/scores, and keeping only the best for each user? This should help you massively.

Comment: Would a pure numpy solution work for you? Not that I have a problem with pandas, but numpy is likely to be faster, and I don't know enough pandas to make it good.

Comment: @IvanLibedinsky Because that won't work. Look at the 4th bullet in my question. The best score of user `a` is not useful, because the group that relates to is already full.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I believe Pandas works with NumPy under the hood, so I'm not sure whether the exact same solution but using NumPy would work. But go on, feel free to answer the question if you think you got it!

Comment: Please clarify "the best way to distribute." Are we trying to maximise or minimise some objective function?

Comment: Is it possible to add some tag to each group? First time g1,g2,g3 (g11,g21,g31) are being filled, second time g1,g2,g3 (g12,g22,g32) are being filled and so on? Otherwise I'm a bit lost on the method used for distribution :(

Comment: @גלעדברקן All information is already in the question. Please read it thoroughly, as "the best way to distribute" is pretty well described in the OP.

Comment: @IvanLibedinsky Sorry if the question is unclear. What is it exactly what you don't understand? One should basically go over all rows of `df`. For each row, check two things: 1) is the user already in a group?, 2) is the group already full?. If both questions are answered with "no", then assign the user to that group. If one of the questions is answered with "yes", then ignore that row and go on.

Comment: can you define what is __forever__ and what is your expected time?

Comment: @user753642 I had to kill the process because it took 2 hours to reach 25k assignations, so I don't know how much it can take to run completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly an answer, but it got too long for a comment.

Sorting a 20 million dataset shouldn't take *that* long, and everything after it should run in linear time. I have a hunch the deletions get really expensive, specifically the lines `df = df.loc[...]`. Let us imagine you have 20M users, each occurring twice, so 40M rows. Each user will be deleted once. If each user deletion scans the entire DataFrame, that's 20M deletions with an average 20M remaining rows, so 400*10^12 operations.

You can implement the same algorithm without any deletions, in O(1) time per row scanned. Simply keep an "assigned" bit for each user (in lower-level languages you'd have a boolean array). When you assign a user, set its bit to 1. For each row, check that the group has remaining spots *and* the user is unassigned. Now no deletions are necessary; rows with assigned users will be skipped naturally.

Sorry I'm not fluent enough in Python to provide code.

Comment: Even though you didn't provide any code, your idea was on point. I implemented it and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do:

```
df = df.pivot_table(index='user', columns='group', values='score').reset_index().fillna(0)
final = {}
df['sum'] = df.loc[:, 'g1':].sum(axis=1)
for group in members.keys():
    df[group] = df[group] / df['sum']
for group in members.keys():
    df = df.sort_values(group, ascending=False)
    final[group] = list(df.head(members[group])['user'])
    df = df.iloc[members[group]:, :]
final
```

Output:

```
{'g1': ['f', 'h', 'd'], 'g2': ['g', 'c'], 'g3': ['b']}
```

Explaination: For each user I'm calculating how relevant he is to any group in comperison to all the groups. Then every group gets the users who are the most oriented to that group, and I remove those users, and do the same with the other groups.

Comment: That seems to work ok, but it's just by chance. If you iterate along `reversed(['g1', 'g2', 'g3'])` instead of `['g1', 'g2', 'g3']`, the result changes. Therefore, your output is dependent of the order in which the groups are listed, which is incorrect.

Comment: @Tendero since you yourself do not have a strict algorithem to work by to "maximize return", I think it is legit that there can be variance in the results, as you said youself "I'm willing to take a sub-optimal solution if necessary". And since you can not determine what is the "correct" answer, how can you determine that any solution is "incorrect" as long as it make sense? Would you say for example that the entire `knn` model is "incorrect", since its final results varias uppon different starting points?

Comment: I see your point. The problem is that I was expecting something rather random or heuristical when I said that I could take a sub-optimal solution. This process seems rather deterministic, and thus I'm not convinced by the fact that it can have variance in its results. My solution returns always the same output, independently of the way the dictionary `members` is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an attempt following Cătălin Frâncu suggestion (using numpy instead of pandas)

- in OP

This is a simplified version to show the dispatching according to your requirement.

- in test

There is the direct access to the `ref` array (instead of using a mapping (`user_id` as in `OP`))

I have not sorted by score (which is of few interest)

The dispatching seems to slow down around 9M most likely because all the users have been dispatched

`n_users = 1e5` takes around `3s` while `1e7` I don't know I quit before.

```
def OP():
    groups = [0,3,2,1] #respectively group
    ref = []
    users = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h']
    user_id = {}
    for i in range(len(users)):
        user_id[users[i]] = i
        ref.append(False)
    entries = []
    entries.append(('h',1,'0.98'))
    entries.append(('e',1,'0.98'))
    entries.append(('d',1,'0.90'))
    entries.append(('c',2,'0.80'))
    entries.append(('c',1,'0.78'))
    entries.append(('e',3,'0.60'))
    entries.append(('a',1,'0.54'))
    entries.append(('b',3,'0.53'))
    entries.append(('g',2,'0.51'))
    entries.append(('d',3,'0.51'))
    entries.append(('a',2,'0.47'))
    entries.append(('h',2,'0.28'))
    entries.append(('f',1,'0.27'))
    entries.append(('g',1,'0.25'))
    entries.append(('b',1,'0.02'))
    entries.append(('b',2,'0.02'))
    entries.append(('c',3,'0.01'))

    out = []
    for u,g,s in entries:
        if ref[user_id[u]] == True:
            continue
        if groups[g] > 0:
            groups[g]-=1
            out.append((u,g,s))
            ref[user_id[u]] = True

    print(out)
    #[('h', 1, '0.98'), ('e', 1, '0.98'), ('d', 1, '0.90'), ('c', 2, '0.80'), ('b', 3, '0.53'), ('g', 2, '0.51')]

def test():
    import numpy as np
    n_users = int(1e7)
    n_groups = 10
    groups = [3,1e6,1e7,1e6,1e6,1e6,1e6,1e6,1e6,1e6]

    print('allocating array')
    N = n_users * n_groups
    dscores = np.random.random((N,1))
    dusers = np.random.randint(0, n_users, (N,1))
    dgroups = np.random.randint(0, n_groups, (N,1))

    print('building ref')
    ref = np.zeros(n_users, dtype=int)

    print('hstack')
    entries = np.hstack((dusers, dgroups, dscores))

    print('dispatching')
    out = np.zeros((n_users, 3))
    z = 0
    counter = 0
    for e in entries:
        counter += 1
        if counter % 1e6 == 0:
            print('ccc', counter)
        u,g,s = e
        u = int(u)
        g = int(g)
        if ref[u] == 1:
            continue
        if groups[g] > 0:
            groups[g]-=1
            out[z][0] = u
            out[z][1] = g
            out[z][2] = s
            ref[u] = 1
            z += 1
            if z % 1e5==0:
                print('z : ', z)
    print('done')

OP()
test()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am by no mean an expert at Numba, and this might be slower. But I have, in the past, have success writing complex algorithms using Numba and loops. If you have a lot of data you might need to change int8 to a bigger datatype.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import numba

# Basic setup:
users = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h', 'a','b','c','g','h', 'b','c','d','e']
groups = ['g1']*8 + ['g2']*5 + ['g3']*4
scores = [0.54, 0.02, 0.78, 0.9 , 0.98, 0.27, 0.25, 0.98, 0.47, 0.02, 0.8, 0.51, 0.28, 0.53, 0.01, 0.51, 0.6 ]
df = pd.DataFrame({'user': users,
                   'group': groups,
                   'score': scores}).sort_values('score', ascending=False)

# Convert user, groups and limits to numbers:
df['user'] = df.user.astype('category')
df['group'] = df.group.astype('category')
df['usercat'] = df.user.cat.codes
df['groupcat'] = df.group.cat.codes

member_mapping_temp = dict( enumerate(df['group'].cat.categories ) )

members = {'g1': 3,
           'g2': 2,
           'g3': 1}

member_map = np.array([(x,members.get(y)) for x,y in member_mapping_temp.items()])

# Define numba njit function to solve problem:
from numba import types
from numba.typed import Dict, List
int_array = types.int8[:]

@numba.njit()
def calc_scores(numpy_array, member_map):
    member_map_limits = Dict.empty(
      key_type=types.int8,
      value_type=types.int8,
    )
    member_count = Dict.empty(
      key_type=types.int8,
      value_type=types.int8,
    )
    memeber_list = []
    for ix in range(len(member_map)):
        group = member_map[ix,0]
        limit = member_map[ix,1]
        member_map_limits[group] = limit
        member_count[group] = 0

    seen_users = set()

    for ix in range(len(numpy_array)):
        user = numpy_array[ix,0]
        group = numpy_array[ix,1]
        if user in seen_users:
            continue
        if member_map_limits[group] == member_count[group]:
            continue
        member_count[group] = member_count[group] + 1
        memeber_list.append((group,user))
        seen_users.add(user)

    return memeber_list

# Call function:
res = calc_scores(df[['usercat','groupcat']].to_numpy(), member_map)

# Add result to DF
res = pd.DataFrame(res, columns=['group','member'])

# Map back to values
res['group'] = pd.Categorical.from_codes(codes=res['group'], dtype=df['group'].dtype)
res['member'] = pd.Categorical.from_codes(codes=res['member'], dtype=df['user'].dtype)
```

Please let me know if this is any faster on the real dataset.